# What is the difference between cross compiler and native compiler with -mtune flag?

Tags: gcc, kernel, cross-compiling

I have these flags in my `Makefile` and it works:

```
gcc -mtune=i386 -m32
ld -m elf_i386
```

What is the difference between those and cross compiler `i386-elf-gcc`?